# Cannot prime method call in Rhino Mocks

Tags: mocking, rhino-mocks

I have tried the following:

```
var getAllResponse = new GetAllResponse();
// Prime the GetAll method
var mockILineOfBusinessService = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ILineOfBusinessService>();
mockILineOfBusinessService.Expect(i => i.GetAll(new GetAllRequest())).Return(getAllResponse);
```

This is from the class I am testing:

```
public static string GetTeamForFocusArea(this ILineOfBusinessService lineOfBusinessService)
{
    ...
    GetAllResponse response = lineOfBusinessService.GetAll(new GetAllRequest());
    ...
}
```

In the above example the response type is always equal to null after the call to `GetAll()`

Could anyone point me in the right direction pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're defining an expectation that when GetAll() is executed with a specific instance of GetAllRequest, you'll return the getAllResponse you earlier set up.  However, inside your GetTeamForFocusArea call, you're making a call to GetAll with a totally different instance of GetAllRequest (it's the one you're creating at that time).  Since the instances don't match, Rhino.Mocks sees this as a different call and doesn't return your expectation.

Set up your expectation to IgnoreArguments() since it appears you don't care what is passed to GetAll, you just want it to return a specific result.

Comment: Thanks Patrick. I also found that by using a Stub instead of a Mock it would also work.

Comment: Actually Stub also needed IgnoreArguments